# How to enable Codesandbox auto complete again?

Tags: codesandbox

Well, Codesandbox stopped working properly from one day to another, it doesn't auto complete or make any suggestions while writing code and emmet abbreviation doesn't work either. I went to File -> Preferences -> Settings and enabled JavaScript Autoclosing Tags checkbox on but still not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn Emmet back on - for autocompleting tag and component names. Not sure when, or why, this was removed from the default behavior when it's the default behavior of just about every other editor.